# How do I access the Model Name in save_formset

Tags: django, django-admin

Basically I have one Parent Model and Many Child Model. In admin.py I am using Inlines on all of them.
I have to use save_formset to save the inline models. In one particular Inline/formset, I want to throw a message to the user based on some information on that model. So I want to know the name of the model. How do I access the Model Name in save_formset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ModelFormSet instances hold the model as an attribute, so you can just :

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    if formset.model == ModelClass:
        do something...
```

Comment: You can check either for class identity, like I did, or check against the model name with formset.model._meta.object_name which is less robust.